# How do I catch the right exception?

Tags: c#

I have the method below. Anytime myResult variable is empty, I get a 500 internal server
error. Various scenarios can make myResult empty.

How do I catch the right exception and not a 500 internal server error ?

```
            try
            {
                var myResult = await _myRepository.GetDataAsync(Id);

                if (!myResult.Any())
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Unable to retrieve record");
                }

            return myResult;                   
            }
            catch (HttpProxyException ex)
            {
                string errorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
                throw new ArgumentException(errorMessage);
            }
```

Comment: inspect inner exception? That might have the actual exception.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The issue is where I throw this exception, it is not hitting the catch block within its method. It is going back to the catch block where it was called in the controller.

Comment: If you don't know how to inspect exceptions, stop what you're doing and take a basic programming course. Trust me, it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your `_myRepository.GetDataAsync(Id);` to throw the **HttpProxyException**. So you can't check if `myResult` is empty because the error throw earlier.

You can adapt your code as follow :

```
var myResult;

try
{
    myResult = await _myRepository.GetDataAsync(Id);
catch (HttpProxyException ex)
{
    string errorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
    throw new ArgumentException(errorMessage);
}

if (!myResult.Any())
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Unable to retrieve record");
}

return myResult;
```

In this scenario, the 500 internal server error throw only when you try to get the data but received the error. If you succeed to get the result but there is no datas, you throw your custom exception.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, your code will only catch `HttyPRoxyException` type exceptions. So your `ArgumentException` exception it won't be caught.

But you can have multiple catch clauses to handle different exception types. They are evaluated in order from first to last, and the first one with a matching signature will handle it.

For example you could use

```
        try
        {
            var myResult = await _myRepository.GetDataAsync(Id);

            if (!myResult.Any())
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unable to retrieve record");
            }

            return myResult;                   
        }
        catch (HttpProxyException ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
            throw new ArgumentException(errorMessage);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            //Do something different here;
        }
```

You could also put a generic catch at the end to trap any other Exception types, if desired.

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Do whatever;
        }
```

NB: One thing to be aware of is that by throwing a new Exception in the Catch, you will be losing the earlier stack trace. This can make it harder to pinpoint the exact location of the offending code.

One way to help with this problem is to include the original exception with the new one, i.e.

```
    catch (HttpProxyException ex)
    {
        string errorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
        throw new ArgumentException(errorMessage, ex);
    }
```